# Compiling a specific version of a freeBSD utility

Tags: freebsd, make

I want to compile and run a specific version of a FreeBSD utility from the source code.

For example, I downloaded the repo for the following utility: https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/9/sbin/routed/

However, when I run the `make` command, I get the following error:

```
"../Makefile.inc", line 3: Cannot open ../Makefile.inc
make: fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue
*** [all] Error code 1
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the whole FreeBSD src tree, not just one subdirectory.

The FreeBSD builsystem uses a lot of Makefiles which are including each other. 
Your build fails because one of the required Makefiles doesn't exist on your filesystem.

Comment: I'm sure the OP would welcome a bit more detail.